# XSD.exe (.Net 2.0) download?

Tags: visual-studio, xsd, xml-serialization, visual-studio-2005, xsd.exe

I need an older version of XSD.exe (comes with VS 2005), preferably a version compatible with .Net 2.0, to generate classes.

Could somebody provide an existing (official) link or possibly upload a copy?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you download and install [.NET Framework 2.0 Software Development Kit (SDK) (x86)](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=19988)
or [.NET Framework 2.0 Software Development Kit (SDK) (x64)](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=15354)

You should be able to find the xsd.exe in

> C:\Program Files\Microsoft.NET\SDK\v2.0\Bin

I tested it with a new project targeting the 2.0 framework and it compiled fine in VS2008. Hopefully it will work too in VS2005.

Comment: Awesome, thanks! I'm actually using VS2012, but the project is targeted for FW 2.0.

Comment: 300Mb seems rather a large download for such  a small tool

Comment: Well it's the complete sdk and not just the tool after all. Unless I'm mistaken, you cannot have it any other way from Microsoft, if you don't have the Visual Studio that came with that version of the framework. You can find it somewhere else on the web, but probably not from Microsoft. It's just that I prefer official source.